# In Lean, how can i get the element from an exists_unique in a definition

Tags: math, definition, function-definition, theorem-proving, lean

I want to make the following

```
variables {Ω : Type} (P:set Ω → Ω → Prop)(a:Ω)

def G :set Ω → Ω:=
begin
  intro V,
  by_cases h: ∃!u : Ω, P V u,
  --I want to use the u that is unique as return in this case, and in the other case use the a
  sorry,
  exact a,
end
```

I tried using the exists.elim and exists_unique.elim but i can't figure out how to use them properly, also I can't use h.some because I'm not using the axiom of choice.
I just want to know how to construct the function proving it's well defined, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`classical.some h`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/classical.some) to obtain a witness using the axiom of choice. Note that you are already using the axiom of choice via the `by_cases` tactic.

If you allow yourself to assume `fintype Ω`, then you can use [`fintype.choose h`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/fintype.choose) to use brute force instead of an axiom.